# Web page delay android sleep

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am developing a Web page with some dulcimer tablature on it. In use, my tablet is going to sleep in the middle of me learning a tab. Is it possible in a Web page to delay sleep? Not prevent. Maybe for 10 or 15 minutes extra.  Preferably  using jquery. 
Thanks again guys, 
Todd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt it at this time. This would be a huge drain on resources and if other web sites did this, I wouldn't visit them.